# Why is this not a statement

Tags: java, android-studio

I am posting some data to a webservice here is the snippet:

```
try {
    response = UniversalHttpUrlConnection.postJSONObject(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_one), UniversalHashMapToJSONObjectParams.createObjectForParams(deleteMap));
    System.out.println("Response from del task" + response);

    if(response != null) 
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

    System.out.println("Deletion" + DatabaseHandler.getInstance(ctx).removeReceipt(receipt));

} catch (JSONException report) {
    report.printStackTrace();
}
```

My IDE is complaining about:

```
if(response != null) 
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

**The exact statement being: 
Not a statement** - Why is this happening, am I missing something here?

if I use:

```
if (response != null) {
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
}
```

The IDE does not complain.

---

For details here is my complete method:

```
public static void deleteReceipt(Receipt receipt, Context ctx) {

    SessionManager sessionManager;
    sessionManager = new SessionManager(ctx);
    HashMap<String, String> map = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
    String email = map.get("email");

    if (CheckConnection.isNetworkConnected(ctx)) {

        System.out.println("local id " + receipt._id);
        Receipt rec = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(ctx).getReceipt(receipt._id);

        String webReceiptId = rec.web_receipt_id;
        System.out.println("WebReceipt ID = " + webReceiptId);
        if (webReceiptId.equalsIgnoreCase("dummy")) {
            // Delete from local
            System.out.println("Deletion" + DatabaseHandler.getInstance(ctx).removeReceipt(receipt));
        } else {
            // delete from server
            // delete from local
            HashMap<String, String> deleteMap = new HashMap<>();
            deleteMap.put("email", email);
            deleteMap.put("type", "Android");
            deleteMap.put("key", Utility.getencryptkey());
            deleteMap.put("task_id", webReceiptId);
            deleteMap.put("receipt_id", String.valueOf(receipt._id));

            String response = null;
            try {
                response = UniversalHttpUrlConnection.postJSONObject(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_one),
                        UniversalHashMapToJSONObjectParams.createObjectForParams(deleteMap));
                System.out.println("Response from del task" + response);

                if (response != null) {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                }

                System.out.println("Deletion" + DatabaseHandler.getInstance(ctx).removeReceipt(receipt));

            } catch (JSONException report) {
                report.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A variable declaration such as `JSONObject jObj = ...` must be inside a block.

Therefore either :

```
        if(response != null) {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        }
```

or

```
        JSONObject jObj = ...
        if(response != null)
            jObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

are valid.

Comment: Oh my! I did not know that, any particular reason this is enforced?

Comment: @User3 Well, when you declare a variable, it must have a scope. When you declare it the way you tried, inside an if statement without brackets, it gets the same scope as that of the if statement. Now, what if you access that variable after if statement? In theory that variable was only declared if the if statement was true. So the compiler doesn't know if the variable is declared or not. Therefore it's not allowed.

Answer (score 12):

What you've got is a local variable declaration - and that isn't allowed on its own as a statement... because it's pointless. Why declare a variable that you're not going to be able to use, because it's immediately out of scope? The compiler is trying to stop you from making a mistake, basically.

In JLS terms, there's a [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement) and a [Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block) - a Block contains BlockStatements, which are statements, class declarations or local variable declarations... and local variable declarations aren't statements.

Answer (score 0):

In JLS terms, there's a Statement and a Block - a Block contains BlockStatements, which are statements, class declarations or local variable declarations... and local variable declarations aren't statements.